# Unable to activate virtual environment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am on Windows 10, Python 3.10.2. Here are the commands that I ran to create the virtual environment:

Here are my versions for packages:

```
virtualenv==16.7.5
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.6
```

1. I installed the virtual environment.

```
D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning>python -m pip install virtualenv
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in d:\python\lib\site-packages (16.7.5)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (d:\python\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\python\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Then I ran these commands:

```
D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning>python -m virtualenv venv310
D:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py:24: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  import distutils.spawn
D:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py:25: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
  import distutils.sysconfig
Using base prefix 'D:\\python'
New python executable in D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning\venv310\Scripts\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2632, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 860, in main
    create_environment(
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1156, in create_environment
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1719, in install_python
    fix_local_scheme(home_dir, symlink)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1805, in fix_local_scheme
    if sysconfig._get_default_scheme() == "posix_local":
AttributeError: module 'sysconfig' has no attribute '_get_default_scheme'. Did you mean: 'get_default_scheme'?
```

Here are the commands I ran for activating the virtual environment and none of them worked:

```
D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning>venv310/scripts/activate
'venv310' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning>python venv310/scripts/activate
python: can't open file 'D:\\voice-cloning\\real-time-voice-cloning\\venv310\\scripts\\activate': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning>venv310/Scripts/activate
'venv310' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning>activate
'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning>cd venv310

D:\voice-cloning\real-time-voice-cloning\venv310>.\Scripts\activate
'.\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the creation of venv was stalled due to an error. It is really hard to guess what went wrong by just looking at your question. Please provide you python version and ways to reproduce your error.

Comment: Please read the VENV [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=venv). Do you wish to activate an existing or create a new venv?

Comment: @NikhilDevadiga My Python version is 3.10.2. I am adding a bit more information to the question. :)

Comment: Please also add the ```virtualenv``` version. You can get this by typing this out in the terminal ```pip freeze```

Comment: Thanks for the clear instructions @NikhilDevadiga :). I have added the version information for `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper-win`.

Comment: Looks like ```virtualenv==16.7.5``` is too old for ```python 3.10.2```.

Comment: Yes, I am going ahead with `conda` to set up different Python versions. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using python 3.10.2 and virtualenv 16.7.5 gives me the same error. Looks like virtualenv 16.7.5 is too old for 3.10.2. Upgrade you package with this command and everything will work out.

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil. How did you test it out so quickly on your system?

Comment: I mean did you already have Python 3.10.2 installed?

Comment: Yes. I had python 3.10.2 and the latest virtualenv which I have been using for a couple of months now so I knew this works. I just guessed that you have an older version of virtualenv which doesn't work. Quickly executing couple of commands ```pip install --upgrade virutalenv==16.7.5``` ```python -m virtualenv venv``` and I could reproduce your error :^)

Comment: by far the best solution, before that i had done sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils, sudo apt-get install python3.10-distutils with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the windows PATH variable there is an entry with your python installation and the scripts subfolder eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\ and C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts
When using pip install virtualenv, make sure that you run cmd as administrator. Otherwise, there might an access denied error during installation and virtualenv will not be installed properly.
Make sure that virtualenv has been installed correctly. Check in the python scripts subfolder - there must exist an .exe named virtualenv.exe. If not, uninstall will pip uninstall virtualenv and install again.

Comment: Thanks Inshaal. I will try them and let you know. :)